# How can I change the font color of the VS2012 Source Control Explorer window?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, team-foundation-server

I am using Visual Stuido 2012 Integrated Shell with Team Explorer.
I would like to change the default font color of the mapped and not mapped folders in the Source Control Explorer (in the treeview).

I tried the Visual Studio Color Theme editor, but it seems like the font color of the Source Control Explorer and the Team Explorer can not be changed by it.
I also looked at Tools|Options|Environment|Fonts and Color for a setting but did not find anything.

Is it possible to change the font color? How?